# How do I autocomplete nested, multi-level subcommands?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, compgen

I am trying to develop an autocomplete or tab-complete feature for my own set of commands.

For example, assume foo is my binary:

```
CLI>> foo [TAB] [TAB]
```

It should show the main commands `configure` and `show`.

Then if I select `configure`, it should show the subcommands `CM`, `DSP` and `NPU`:

```
CLI>> foo configure [TAB] [TAB]
DSP NPU CM`
```

I only know how to tab-complete and display for the first level - how can I get the second level as well?

I will place this in `/etc/completion.d`.

My Code:

```
_foo()
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    words=("${COMP_WORDS[@]}")
    cword=$COMP_CWORD
    opts="configure show"
}
```

I'm stuck as how to add sub commands `CM` `DSP` `NPU` under `configure`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's an example script for your two-level case (with a section for subcommands of `show` to show how it's done - you can just delete those three lines if they're not relevant to your case):

```
_foo()
{
    local cur prev

    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    case ${COMP_CWORD} in
        1)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "configure show" -- ${cur}))
            ;;
        2)
            case ${prev} in
                configure)
                    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "CM DSP NPU" -- ${cur}))
                    ;;
                show)
                    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "some other args" -- ${cur}))
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        *)
            COMPREPLY=()
            ;;
    esac
}

complete -F _foo foo
```

Hopefully it's fairly obvious from that example how you'd extend it to three-level commands etc., as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I was in need of. Let me come back to you as I advance.

Comment: Interesting, how much cool stuff one can find around here ;-)

Comment: I've executed in my terminal. Is not woking. I am typing "configure show <tab>" but nothing happens.

Comment: @sensorario the script defines a command `foo` with two mutually exclusive arguments `configure` and `show` (which themseleves have sub-arguments). Try typing `foo` and then hitting Tab a couple of times …

Comment: The problem was that I was putting code inside a file and the executing it. Eveything works with `source file.sh` where file.sh contains the script. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey @ZeroPiraeus, would you mind giving some pseudocode of how a three-level setup would work? your example seems to be the cleanest I have seen googling around but can't figure out how to do a third level. Thanks!

Comment: For three-level you will add one more case with it's options.