# How to auto-complete a multi-level command aliased to a single command?

Tags: bash, docker, autocomplete, alias

Say I have two bash functions:

```
dock() { sudo docker $@ ;}
```

and

```
dock-ip() { sudo docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $@ ;}
```

How to get bash auto-completion working with the **second function**?

With the first one, it is as easy as adding:

```
_completion_loader docker; complete -F _docker dock
```

This will not work for the second one. The autocomplete source for Docker is in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker` on Debian Stretch. I have more functions like `dock-run`, `dock-exec`, etc. so I don't want to write a custom completion function for each of them.

Also, `complete -F _docker_container_inspect dock-ip` only partially works; <kbd>tab</kbd> only lists containers, not completes partial strings.

---

Research:

[How do I autocomplete nested, multi-level subcommands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879322/how-do-i-autocomplete-nested-multi-level-subcommands) <-- needs custom functions

https://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases <-- automated for top commands only

Answer (score 4):

With a combined hour of bash completion experience, I took apart the docker completion script (`/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/docker`) and the `bash_completion.sh` script to come up with a wrapper function:

```
# Usage:
#   docker_alias_completion_wrapper <completion function> <alias/function name>
#
# Example:
#   dock-ip() { docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $@ ;}
#   docker_alias_completion_wrapper __docker_complete_containers_running dock-ip
function docker_alias_completion_wrapper {
  local completion_function="$1";
  local alias_name="$2";

  local func=$(cat <<EOT
    # Generate a new completion function name
    function _$alias_name() {
        # Start off like _docker()
        local previous_extglob_setting=\$(shopt -p extglob);
        shopt -s extglob;

        # Populate \$cur, \$prev, \$words, \$cword
        _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur prev words cword;

        # Declare and execute
        declare -F $completion_function >/dev/null && $completion_function;

        eval "\$previous_extglob_setting";
        return 0;
    };
EOT
  );
  eval "$func";

  # Register the alias completion function
  complete -F _$alias_name $alias_name
}
export -f docker_alias_completion_wrapper
```

I then created my alias/functions like this:

```
# Get container IP
dock-ip() { docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $@ ;}
docker_alias_completion_wrapper __docker_complete_containers_running dock-ip

# Execute interactive container
dock-exec()  { docker exec -i -t --privileged $@ ;}
docker_alias_completion_wrapper __docker_complete_containers_all dock-exec

...
```

Be sure to call `_completion_loader docker;` at the top of your profile aliases script to load the main Docker completion scripts. I invite more skilled bash programmers to improve this answer, please.

Comment: nice, put line `_completion_loader docker;` to your first sample code for more lazy people :P